# ASP.NET-5 test libraries do not discover main code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, xunit.net

I have one class library that targets `net451` and `dotnet5.4`. Both are the recommended monikers for class libraries in ASP.NET vNext. However my unit tests are based on xUnit and therefore have to target `dnx451` and `dnxcore50`. This however results in my test project not discovering the class I want to test. It simply says *Cannot resolve Symbol*

Is there a way around this, except re targeting my class library to the same monikers as my test project (which would be really stupid, tbh)

Here is the project.json from my test project:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "description": "Test Class Library",
    "authors": [ "Robert" ],
    "tags": [ "" ],
    "projectUrl": "",
    "licenseUrl": "",
    "dependencies": {
        "SemanticVersion": "1.0.0-*",
        "xunit": "2.1.0",
        "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-rc1-build204"
    },
    "commands": {
        "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { },
        "dnxcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
                "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
                "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
                "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
                "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, here is the project.json from the main library:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "SemanticVersion Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Robert" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For further debugging, here is the code in question:

```
namespace Semver
{
    public class SemanticVersion
    {
        public int Major { get; set; }

        public int Minor { get; set; }

        public int Patch { get; set; }

        public string Prerelease { get; set; }

        public string Build { get; set; }

        public static SemanticVersion Parse(string versionString, bool strict = false)
        {
            // Code here
        }
    }
}

namespace SemanticVersionTest
{
    using Xunit;
    using Semver;

    public class ParseTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void ParseMajor()
        {
            SemanticVersion version = SemanticVersion.Parse("1");

            Assert.Equal(1, version.Major);
            Assert.Equal(0, version.Minor);
            Assert.Equal(0, version.Patch);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you share how your test project's project.json looks like?

Comment: I added it to the main question, I also added the main project project.json file

Comment: I am unable to repro the issue that your seeing...So is the reference to the package `SemanticVersion` resolved as expected?...

Comment: The project.json is not giving anny error, if that's what you mean. But if I write the code VS tells me it can't resolve the Symbol. I edited the original question with the code in question.

Comment: Is the dependency really called `SemanticVersion` or is that just the namespace you used? Are both projects part of the same VS solution?

Comment: Both projects are part of the same VS Solution. The Main Project is called *SemanticVersion* with the default namespace `Semver`. As I already stated: When editing test *project.json* file in VS I get no errors, so I assume that the reference is found correctly, however after that VS cannot resolve the symbol. However and that I find strange: If I place the caret over the (test-)code and press F12 VS navigates to the referenced code as usual. Compiling isn't working though and I get the error window full of *Cannot resolve Symbol* errors.

Comment: Are you using Resharper?

Comment: @JeremyFrey Yes I do, but I already updated it to the latest version and the error persists.

Comment: I'm having the same issue: when referencing a *Class Library (Package)* project from an MVC 6 project within the same solution, using VS 2015 Community, all references to classes defined within the package are shown in red text (no red squigglies) and show the mouse-over error "Cannot resolve symbol 'x'". I am also using Resharper 10. Which I just updated to 10.2 and noticed the following installation error: `The CrossAppDomainPointer` is NULL. This seems like the likely culprit.

Answer (score 0):

As described in my earlier comment, I was also having this issue. In my case, the issue was with ReSharper as the project would still build and I could still use F12 to navigate. I had noticed, while updating R#, I received an error

> CrossAppDomainPointer is NULL.

I was able to resolve this issue by reinstalling R# after launching the installer as Administrator. Hope this helps!